# Halbach array magnetic polarity

Tags: forces, magnetic-fields, halbach-array

[image]

Above is a [Halbach array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array) arrangement of magnets that has its field flux concentrated on one side and cancelled out on the other. Now I wish to know the polarity (if there exist any) of the side with flux concentration and that of the other side. And it's claimed that exposing an unmagnetized sheet of polymer binder added with ferromagnetic materials to a rotating magnetic field produces a magnet with the same configuration as a Halbach array, how accurate is this? And lastly, would two Halbach magnets with opposite arrangement (hence opposite polarity) stick strongly to each other due to the field concentration if the sides with the concentration are facing?